# Inheritance and virtual function can't compile (from Head First DP)

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I am new to Design Pattern, and I'm trying the first example of (Head First Design Patterns) but I'm trying to code it in C++. I can't compile my code! I don't know why. Here's my code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class QuackBehavior
{
public:
    virtual void quack();
    virtual ~QuackBehavior();
};
class Quack : public QuackBehavior
{
public:
    void quack()
    {
        cout<<"Quacking"<<endl;
    }
};

class MuteQuack : public QuackBehavior
{
public:
    void quack()
    {
        cout<<"<<< Silence >>>"<<endl;
    }
};

class Squeak : public QuackBehavior
{
public:
    void quack()
    {
        cout<<"Squeak"<<endl;
    }
};

class FlyBehavior
{
public:
    virtual void fly();
    virtual ~FlyBehavior();
};

class FlyWithWings : public FlyBehavior
{
public:
    void fly()
    {
        cout<<"I'm flying"<<endl;
    }
};



class FlyNoWay : public FlyBehavior
{
public:
    void fly()
    {
        cout<<"I can't fly"<<endl;
    }
};

class Duck
{
public:
    FlyBehavior *flyBehavior;
    QuackBehavior *quackBehavior;

    void display();
    void performFly()
    {
        flyBehavior->fly();
    }
    void performQuack()
    {
        quackBehavior->quack();
    }

};

class MallardDuck : public Duck
{
public:
    MallardDuck()
    {
        quackBehavior = new Quack();
        flyBehavior = new FlyWithWings();
    }
};



int main()
{

    Duck *mallard = new MallardDuck;

    cout<<"Test"<<endl;

    mallard->performFly();
//  mallard->performQuack();

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: compiles fine on VC10. What error are you getting and on what line?

Comment: There is no need to allocate `MallardDuck` with `new`, you could just put it on the stack. Furthermore, you should probably use `std::unique_ptr<FlyBehavior> flyBehavior` and `std::unique_ptr<QuackBehavior> quackBehavior` because, as it is, you are leaking memory.

Comment: Matthieu thanks for trying to help. My pointer "mallard" is a base class pointer, so I can use it to point to subclasses, this is part of the exercice. My be using smart pointers is better, but this doesn't solve my compiling problem.

Comment: Zadirion, thanks for trying to help. I'm using Mac (10.8.2) and Eclipse. The error is: make: *** [myprog] Error 1 myprog C/C++ Problem Description Resource Path Location Type symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 myprog . I have no problem compiling other codes on my machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a compile error because you have not provided default definitions for functions in class QuackBehavior and class FlyBehavior.
Either you could provide default implementation or make the functions pure virtual.

Make the below two changes and your code should compile fine.

```
class QuackBehavior
{
      public:
          virtual void quack(){}
          virtual ~QuackBehavior(){}
};

class FlyBehavior
{
  public:
      virtual void fly(){}
      virtual ~FlyBehavior(){}
};
```

OR

```
class FlyBehavior
{
  public:
      virtual void fly() = 0;
};

class QuackBehavior
{
  public:
      virtual void quack() = 0;
};
```

Comment: Many thanks Rush, you're right, both of them works. I have a question, in your second proposition, why I don't have to define a the destructor if I use a virtual function? The compiler gives warning if I skip the destructor.

Comment: You should define a virtual destructor actually not sure why I removed it. However ideally you should not make it pure virtual, you should have an empty implementation if anything else you would get a compile error. The only reason you would want to make destructor pure virtual is when you want to make a class abstract and if it does not have any pure virtual function. However, even in that case you need to have an empty implementation.